# Android Show dialog when Runnable with Progress Dialog finishes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment. When the Fragment is created I want to show a Progress Dialog for 3 seconds, then dismiss it and show a pop up dialog. I attach below my code.

From the onCreate() of my Fragment:

```
final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "text..", true);
myPd_ring.setCancelable(false);
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
            myPd_ring.dismiss();

        }
    }).start();

showPopup(0, 8, 1, "Next photo");
```

And my popup method:

```
public void showPopup(final int type, int photoNo, int currPhoto, String message) {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_erroare);
    dialog.setCancelable(false);
    TextView textHeader;
    TextView textContent;

    textHeader = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_titlu);
    textContent = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text_error);

    textHeader.setText("Procedura fotografiere");
    textContent.setText("Poza nr. " + currPhoto+ " of" + noPhoto+
            ". " + message);

    if (type == 0) {

    }
    Button btn_nu = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_nu);
    if (type == 0) {
        btn_nu.setText("NU");

    }
    btn_nu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    btn_nu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    Button btn_da = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button_da);
    btn_da.setText("Fotografiere");
    btn_da.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (type == 0) {
                captureImage();
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
}
```

The problem is that my `ProgressDialog` doesn't appear, the popup appears directly. If I put my pop up invoking method in the new `Thread()` body I get an error. It seems that you can invoke a dialog from a `Runnable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the below code:

```
final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait",
            "text..", true);
    myPd_ring.setCancelable(false);
    myPd_ring.show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
             myPd_ring.dismiss();
                 showPopup(0, 8, 1, "Next photo");

            }
        }, 3000);
```

If you have any query please let me know.

Comment: Ok Gabi :-) enjoy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Never use sleep() in final APP.
try this way, new a Runnable(), and call postDelay(runnable, delayTimes) on a Handle.

Answer (score 0):

Android Handler has a handy method postDelay() that does what you need, for example:

```
final ProgressDialog myPd_ring=ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait", "text..", true);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myPd_ring.dismiss();
            // show popup
        }
    }, 3000);
```

In Android, all View related tasks must be executed in the main thread, doing it in other threads will result in error. If you want to do in inside a background task for example, you'll need to use myactivity.runOnUiThread()

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // show my popup
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you. also a good solution. but I voted the other guy because he was first